# Hide audio inside other audio using FFT

Tags: audio

How can i hide audio inside other using FFT, I need to know how to begin and what to do ? the first image is for the first audio and the second which i want to hide
[image: This is th fft of the first signal]

[image: the second image is fft for the audio i want to hide]

Comment: You can use [frequency-shift keying][1]


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency-shift_keying

Comment: Hi Sara- Can you elaborate on what you mean by "hide"?

Comment: i want to make audio  Steganography !!